# What medication would best treat buspirone induced insomnia?

Tags: psychopharmacology

The anxiolytic buspirone causes insomnia in a small minority of patients.  What existent medication would theoretically (or in practice) best treat this insomnia? Buspirone from my understanding is an agonist of the 5-HT1A autoreceptors, has very weak antagonism of the D2 receptors. There is also evidence that one of buspirone's metabolites increases plasma norepinephrine and epinephrine levels. I'm trying to think of a medication that would best block the effects of whatever it is that causes the insomnia. Buspirone is a tad "dirty" in that it and its metabolites affect many things so it's hard to say what causes the insomnia.

Comment: This seems too much like a request for medical advice.

Comment: Well this is supposed to be completely theoretical.

Comment: What medicine to use for a specific side effect symptom caused by a specific drug seems hardly theoretical.

Comment: Ok well this may seem like a request for medical advice. But it is not. And legally speaking, the wording of this question makes it not technically a request for medical advice. So it should be ok. But if you disagree, please let me know. This is my first post here so I want to follow all the rules.

Comment: This question highlights a bit of a grey area with the policy @BryanKrause. There is nothing specifically indicating the fact that it is seeking personal medical advice, but it **could** nevertheless be. I believe you know my position regarding questions seeking personal advice, but in this case, with the way it is written I would give the OP the benefit of the doubt. It is making statements regarding the side effects found for the medication and looking for adjunct medication to counteract said side effects.